# Flashcard Game: How to keep score

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a flashcard game in python for python terms. A few of the specs I'd like it to have are:

1) The program should store scores in a file
2) Scores should keep track of each word and / or key and keep track of how many times guessed correct and incorrect
3) After each guess, the program should tell the user how many times the user has guessed that key correctly and incorrectly

I'm very new to Python and would appreciate the simplest explanation on how to make this work (if at all possible).

Here's what I have:

```
from random import choice
import sys

print("Welcome! Please type 'Start' to begin or 'Quit' to leave")

user_answer = raw_input()

if (user_answer == "quit"):
    quit()  

file = []

words = {
    "break": "Stops repeat of a block or loop", 
    "else": "comes after 'if' to offer an alternative option", 
    "if": "informs computer on how to react depending on key response from user",
    "index": "Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x",
    "dict": "Associates one thing to another no matter what it is",
    "import": "To call a command",
    "def": "to define a word",
    "print": "to send a message to the screen for the user to see",
    "for": "One way to start a loop",
    "while": "Another way to start a loop",
    "elif": "When an 'If'/'Else' situation calls for more than one 'Else'",
    "from": "directs the computer to a location from which to import a command"
}

score = file[]

key = choice(words.keys())
remaining_questions = 3

while remaining_questions > 0:
    print("Which command can accomplish: " + words[key] + "...?")
    user_guess = raw_input()
    print(str(user_guess == key))
    remaining_questions = remaining_questions - 1
```

Comment: Maybe before writing this program, you should get the definitions right. "def: to define a word"? "import: to call a command"? This would help you a lot and create a basis on which to start coding.

Comment: Do you want the saved file to be human readable?

Comment: I'd like the scores to be displayed at the beginning of each game so that the user can view their history. I've been referred to using csv for this function, but I'm working my way through the answers and comparing the three approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's start with the basic: you can store the result in a dict as well and use the `pickle` module to dump that dict into a file. So, the dict structure can be like this:

```
answers[word]['correct']
answers[word]['wrong']
```

I'll make a simple and short code to start that dict with its default values (0s for all the words and guesses) if the file doesn't exist and to load that dict from a file if it does exist, using `Pickle`:

```
from os.path import isfile
from pickle import load

if isfile('answers.bin'):
    # loads the dict from the previously "pickled" file if it exists
    answers = load(open('answers.bin', 'rb'))     
else: 
    # create a "default" dict with 0s for every word
    for word in words.keys():
        answers[word] = {'correct': 0, 'wrong': 0}
```

Then, we will build a `if` statement to check is the user answered correctly:

```
if key == user_guess: # there's no need to cast the `user_guess` to str
    answers[key]['correct'] += 1
else:
    answers[key]['wrong'] += 1
```

Finally, after the while block, we persist that answers dict with pickle, so we can load it later if needed:

```
from pickle import dump
dump(answers, open('answers.bin', 'wb'))
```

Comment: And just replace the dump call with open('ansers.bin', 'w').write(json.dumps(answers)) if you want it to be human readable

Comment: Just remember to `import json ` and use `open('answers.bin').read(json.loads(answers))` to read the file, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping scores in a file is tough - this is what databases (`sqlite3`, for example) could do very well.  If you really want to, you might implement a `Scorer` class like below.  You could add multiple users without much trouble.  It has only two methods you would want to call, namely `add_score` to say someone got a word right and `get_score` to see how they've done on that word, as in :

```
user_scores = Scorer()
user_scores.add_score(words[key])
right, wrong = user_scores.get_score(words[key])
print("You've gotten {:s} right {:d} times and wrong {:d} times".format(
    words[key],
    right,
    wrong))
```

The data would all live in `some_filename.csv`, so as long as you didn't mess with that, you would be fine.

```
import csv
import os

class Scorer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = 'some_filename.csv'
        self._colnames = ["word","right","wrong"]
        self._data = self._load_data()

    def _load_data(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            with open(self.filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(",".join(self._colnames) + "\n")
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            data = {row["word"] : row for row in reader}
        return data

    def _save_data(self):
        with open(self.filename,'wb') as f:
            f.write(",".join(self._colnames) + "\n")
            for word_data in self._data.values():
                row_str = ",".join([str(word_data[col]) for col in self._colnames])
                f.write(row_str + "\n")

    def add_score(self, word, was_right):
        if word not in self._data:
            self._data[word] = {"word": word,"right":0,"wrong":0} 
        if was_right:
            self._data[word]["right"] += 1
        else:
            self._data[word]["wrong"] += 1
        self._save_data

    def get_score(self, word):
        right = self._data.get(word, {}).get("right",0)
        wrong = self._data.get(word, {}).get("wrong",0)
        return right, wrong
```